# Testlink: Getting 500 internal server error on importing test cases

Tags: testlink

I am trying to import test cases from XML file, but getting below error in the browser console.

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)" in file "/lib/testcases/tcImport.php"

Answer (score 0):

In testlink server, administrator need to install php-xml module for  import xml files.

Check for Error logs in testlink server, following error is displayed when user try to import xml without php-xml module.

[php7:error] [pid 12367] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:40469] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in /var/www/html/lib/functions/xml.inc.php:35\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/lib/testcases/tcImport.php(553): simplexml_load_file_wrapper('/var/www/html/g...')\n#1 /var/www/html/lib/testcases/tcImport.php(56): check_xml_tc_tsuite('/var/www/html/g...', '0')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/lib/functions/xml.inc.php on line 35, referer: https://testlink.xxxxx.com/lib/testcases/tcImport.php?containerID=535